# Removing Stop words from a list of strings in R

Tags: r, dplyr, text-mining, tidytext

**Sample data**

Dput code of my data

```
  x <-  structure(list(Comments = structure(2:1, .Label = c("I have a lot of home-work to be completed..", 
    "I want to vist my teacher today only!!"), class = "factor"), 
        Comment_ID = c(704, 802)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -2L))
```

I want to remove the stop words from the above data set using `tidytext::stop_words$word` and also retain the same columns in the output. Along with this how can I remove punctuation in `tidytext` package?

*Note: I don't want to change my dataset into corpus*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can collapse all the words in `tidytext::stop_words$word` into one regex adding word boundaries. However, `tidytext::stop_words$word` is of length 1149 and this might be too big for regex to handle so you can remove few words which are not needed and apply this.

For example taking only first 10 words from `tidytext::stop_words$word`, you can do :

```
gsub(paste0(paste0('\\b', tidytext::stop_words$word[1:10], '\\b', 
     collapse = "|"), '|[[:punct:]]+'), '', x$Comments)


#[1] "I want to vist my teacher today only"    
#    "I have  lot of homework to be completed"
```

Comment: Thanks Ronak, from ``tidytext::stop_words`` I've taken lexicons which are SMART :)

Answer (score 0):

```
clean_tweet = removeWords(clean_tweet, stopwords("english"))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).